# How to edit a Firefox Extension's manifest.json file?

Tags: firefox, browser, customization, manifest, manifest.json

I installed a Firefox Extension and need to customize a keyboard shortcut it uses. Apparently this needs to be done by modifying the Extension's `manifest.json`

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands#shortcut_values):

> Each keyboard shortcut is defined with a name, a combination of keys,
> and a description. ***Once you've defined commands in your extension's
> manifest.json***, you can listen for their associated key combinations
> with the commands JavaScript API.

The problem is that I can't define anything because the .json is read-only in my browser window, and I don't know where (or if) it can be accessed outside of the browser through macOS Finder.

Here's a related question: [How to access the manifest.json file of a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876439/) but it doesn't go into how to *edit* it.

Maybe I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your all extension from this location:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile]\storage\default
```

also check here

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local........
```

and find the extension which you want to edit.

[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CRSf.png) I am showing of Chrome browser I don't have Mozilla.

Please confirm me if you will done through this.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using macOS, so the path is different, but I now that I know to look in the Profiles folder, I know to look in: `/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/...` What's odd is that when I ran a search of my profile folder's contents I could only find one manifest.json file, and it wasn't the one I needed (the one belonging to the extension). I wonder why...